# Orthonormal basis question from textbook

Tags: calculus

Sorry on a phone so this is hard to type:

Consider $p_1 (x) = 1 $and $p_2(x)= ax+b$

Choose $a$ and $b$ so $ p_i (x)$ form an orthonormal basis with respect to the $L_2$ norm derived from the inner product $(u,v) = \int_0^1 uvdx$ on $[0,1]$

Not really sure how to do this textbook problem, any starter tips are good thank you

I have read the wiki page for orthnormal basis but I didn't understand how to solve the problem even still!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says, find $a, b$ such that $\int_0^1 p_1 \cdot p_2 ~ dx = 0$ and $\int_0^1 p_2 \cdot p_2 ~ dx = 1$.

Comment: Wow is it really that simple???

Comment: This, along with the fact that $\int_0^1 p_1\cdot p_1 \, \text{d}x = \int_0^1 1\,\text{d}x = 1$ is all you need to do.

Comment: @user137849, orthonormal basis is one where the inner product of every pair of its elements is $0$ and the norm of each of them is $1$.

Comment: Norm of each pair, or element equals one?

Comment: @user137849, each element. "$L^2$ norm derived from the inner product" means norm is $|x| = \sqrt{(x, x)}$. It's a function of one argument. Note that the root adds nothing here, when checking $|x| = 1$.

Comment: I can't get p2 p2 int equals 1 for a b?